# Another way of solving dictionary search (without LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I would like to ask you if LINQ is the best way to do this dictionary search.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> books = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

Right now I'm using LINQ like this:

```
public List<string> FindAllBooks(string author)
{
    List<string> BooksFound = new List<string>();
    var matchingKeys = books.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(author)).Select(x => x.Key);
    foreach(var item in matchingKeys)
    {
        BooksFound.Add(item);
    }

    return BooksFound;
}
```

Also I'm trying to make this code OOP. If my solution is bad, could you help me understand how to do this properly?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing here? If you don't want to use linq, you want l can do foreach loop. The logic remains the same.

Comment: "Best" is subjective, depends on what your goal is and other factors such as the size of the dataset you're storing. It's definitely not the best way if your dictionary contains 100 million entries, for example. And if you're trying to keep your code "object oriented", you should probably define classes that represent books instead of dealing with dictionarys containing strings and string arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Linq only* solution is something like this:

```
public List<string> FindAllBooks(string author) => books
  .Where(book => book.Value.Contains(author))
  .Select(book => book.Key) 
  .ToList();
```

No Linq solution (*loops only*) can be

```
public List<string> FindAllBooks(string author) {
  List<string> BooksFound = new List<string>();

  foreach (var book in books)
    if (book.Value.Contains(author))
      BooksFound.Add(book.Key);
      
  return BooksFound; 
}
```

Your code (which is *not bad*) is somewhere in between (*both* Linq and loop). `books` dictionary `Key` is some kind of `Id` (is it ISBN?) that's why you *have to scan* the entire dictionary. Would you like to do it with a help of *Linq*, *loops* or a mixture of them is a question of taste, readability etc.

Comment: Looks like Linq is more clear and simpler. I saw somewhere the comparison in effectiveness and Linq is sometimes a bit slower, but is it more popular overall than 'no Linq approach'?

Comment: @Tomasz Majek: unless you have to deal with millions items, it's not the performance (micro if not nanoseconds) that matters. Linq is that popular for its flexibility and easiness to write and maintain.